# Why do we need to return a promise resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

```js
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  return result; // "done!"
}
f().then(result => {
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}).then(r => console.log(r))
```

The above code does not work as intended if I remove the **return** keyword from the second last line. I do not understand why do we need to write a **return**? Does not the **resolve** method of promise essentially does that i.e. return a value?

Comment: There's no point to it at all. `.then((result) => Promise.resolve(result))` is the same as `.then((result) => result)` which is the same as not having the `.then` at all.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between returning value or Promise.resolve from then()](/q/27715275/4642212).

Comment: Yea, I understand that the part was not needed at all to be added. but I added it to understand Promises and in principle it should work, in my opinion. Can you kindly help me understand what is the difference between me writing 'return' on the second last line, and not writing it?

Comment: You don't need the `Promise.resolve(result)` at all.  You just need a return value such as `return result`.  If there's no return value from a `.then()`, then the resolved value of the promise becomes `undefined`.

Comment: without a `try..catch` block, `let result = await promise; return result` is the same as `return promise`. And since no `await` is needed, you can drop the `async` keyword on your function. And `.then(result => return Promise.resolve(result))` does nothing, as others have said. And `.then(r => console.log(r))` is the same as `.then(console.log)`.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not understand why do we need to write a return?

Because if you don't, the fulfillment callback's return value will be `undefined`, as with any other function, which means that the fulfillment value of the promise created by that `then` call will be `undefined` instead of being `result`.

There's no reason for that fulfillment handler at all, it doesn't do anything useful, it just introduces an extra async "tick" into the promise fulfillment. Just remove it:

```
f().then(result => console.log(result))
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I understand that the part was not needed at all to be added. but I added it to understand Promises and in principle it should work, in my opinion.

It's for the reason I mentioned in the first paragraph above: otherwise, the function returns `undefined` (implicitly). It's the difference between `a` and `b` in the following. You might be thinking of *concise* arrow syntax where the body of the function is just an expression and the `return` is implicit, like `c` below:

```js
const a = () => {
    42;
};
const b = () => {
    return 42;
};
const c = () => 42; // No `{` just after the `=>`

console.log(a()); // undefined
console.log(b()); // 42
console.log(c()); // 42
```

In that case, you'd use:

```
f().then(result => result) // If you want that there to understand it better
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

Note there's no `Promise.resolve` there. There's no reason to create another promise; the return value of the fulfillment handler will be used to resolve the promise `then` returned. No need for an extra one.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can remove the entire middle `then`:

```
f().then(r => console.log(r))
```

Second, the last `then` expects an input from the previous one: `r`, which is why we should `return` it.

and last,

```
.then((result) => Promise.resolve(result))
```

is the same as:

```
.then((result) => result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the subtle difference between this:

```
f().then(result => {
  Promise.resolve(result);
}).then(r => console.log(r)); // prints "undefined"
```

compared to this:

```
f().then(result =>
  Promise.resolve(result)
).then(r => console.log(r)); // prints resolved value of `f`
```

In the first example, you are supplying *multiple statements* (inside the brackets) to the `then` handler. Because you are not explicitly returning a value, the return value is undefined, which is what will be seen by subsequent `then` handler.

In the second example, the arrow function is provided a *simple expression* (there are no brackets, and only a single line is supplied). In this case, it is the expression itself which provides the return value for the function.

This [documentation on arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) syntax is a bit more precise.

As others have pointed out, in this contrived example the `Promise.resolve()` is not needed at all, as the value given to the `then` handler is indeed already resolved. So you could just as well do:

```
f().then(r => console.log(r));
```